# Create a menu subitems dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have a designed a Menu using CSS/Bootstrap in my asp.net application but submenus need to create runtime based on user role. Need a idea something like that take parameters to create a Subitems created runtime in website. Please help me to how to achieve this scenario. Anyone's help is appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJbpT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `sub-menu` dynamically. This is one of many ways.

I've created this using without bootstrap to give an idea what goes under the hood. Add class to `sub-menu-items` acc to bootstrap and personal preference.

**Style yourself. I've done basic styling**

```js
const menuItem = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item");
menuItem.forEach((mi) => {
  mi.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const nextSibling = e.target.nextElementSibling;
    nextSibling.classList.toggle("hide");
  });
});

function addSubMenuItem(menuItemId, smi) {
  const menuItem = document.querySelector(`#${menuItemId}`);
  const sibling = menuItem.nextElementSibling;
  smi.forEach((subMenuItemName) => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.classList.add("sub-menu-item");
    li.textContent = subMenuItemName;
    sibling.append(li);
  });
}

addSubMenuItem("home", ["a", "b", "c"]);
addSubMenuItem("blog", ["a"]);
addSubMenuItem("work", ["a", "b", "c", "d", 1, 24]);
addSubMenuItem("about", ["a", "b", "c", 0, 83, 93]);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.menu-item-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-item {
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

ul.sub-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: royalblue;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li.sub-menu-item {
  padding: .25rem 1rem;
}

.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu-item-container">
    <div class="menu-item" id="home">Home</div>
    <ul class="sub-menu hide">
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item-container">
    <div class="menu-item" id="blog">Blog</div>
    <ul class="sub-menu hide"></ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item-container">
    <div class="menu-item" id="work">Work</div>
    <ul class="sub-menu hide"></ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item-container">
    <div class="menu-item" id="about">About</div>
    <ul class="sub-menu hide"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just pass the sub-menu-items as an array. Everything works as intended. It would be better if elements are either a `string` or `number`

Comment: If you want to navigate then marke it `a` tag and add `href` dynamically using `setAttribute` in JS

Comment: create a codesandbox, so that I can understand what exactly what you need...
https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: ok @DIRIYA, Just comment me when you are available, so that we can continue on chat and can clearify what exactly do you need. It is still vague

Comment: ok tell me one by one what do you need

Comment: Do you want to set the href on the dropdown also. Is that right

Comment: I've no Idea about .net. I can help you only with JS

Comment: `a.href = "https://www.google.com";`

Comment: Not a problem, Just add in an array `[]` and replace it with index

Comment: Create an array of object and get the name and url from that object in loop and add in HTML elements. Simple

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/snowy-fire-xzl6p?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark